# Remove services in Sharekit

Tags: ios, sharekit

I used Sharekit in my application. During implementation I included all services in Sharekit.

Now I use only Facebook & Twitter share, I managed to show my action sheet visible only for Facebook & Twitter.

Now I want to remove all unused services like Dropbox,Evernote,Onedrive. As this will increase the size of the application, my intention is to reduce the size of the application by removing the unused services. Anyone please advice.

Comment: I don't think that removing such services changes the size of your app dramatically. Your just "hiding" that services from the user, and the ShareKit is not inside your application, it's part of iOS.

Comment: @beeef thanks. what do you mean by "ShareKit is not inside your application, it's part of iOS".

Comment: Do you use the default UIActivityViewController or do you have any 3rd party framework for that?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Is there any ways to remove dropbox, Evernote ?